# Disable Raspbian MAC advertisement (nmap)

Tags: raspbian, nmap, mac-address

I recently got a Raspberry Pi B+ and installed Raspbian Lite. I'll
make a simple server out of it (SSH only and external LUKS-encrypted
HDD, so I can access my files from everywhere). I ran `nmap` to check
my ports, and got this (actual MAC obscured):

```
MAC Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (Raspberry Pi Foundation)
```

Does someone know where this comes from? And how to hide the MAC
address from other hosts?

Answer (score 1):

Your MAC address will be always visible because that's how ARP layer2 to layer3 (IP) resolution works. Therefore, **you cannot hide your NIC MAC address from anyone in the same subnet.** It's an essential part of operation, equally same as your NIC IP address!

However, you can *change MAC address* on your NIC. In Linux, it's pretty easy:

1. Turn off your interface
2. Set a new MAC address: `ip l set eth0 addr 01:23:45:67:89:ab` (replace `eth0` with your actual interface name responsible for network connectivity on the machine and `01:23:45:67:89:ab` with your MAC address you can imagine)
3. Turn on your interface

All things are to be run as root or with the tools that can configure NIC parameters like IP and/or MAC addresses.

When making new MAC, remember that first member of any unicast MAC must be an even number plus rule of local MAC assignment apply: 02, 06, 0a, 0e.

The changes made by `ip` command are **not** permanent! After next reboot it will be reset to original. For Raspberry pi there is a parameter to be specified in cmdline.txt: `smsc95xx.macaddr=01:23:45:67:89:ab`.

Comment: also please note that there are rules for mac address and it's generally not a good idea to change it, and mostly not needed and will not add to your security

Comment: I do not see anything bad in changing a mac. What are "rules for mac address"? Do you mean certain number assignments to companies making hardware (OUI)? I, for example, always change macs on my portable hardware such as notebooks or public hardware such as wireless routers.

Comment: rules such as having a 1 as second least significant digit of the first octet if you are not the device manufacturer (i.e., if you are changing your MAC address), and using 0 as least significant digit of the same octet because 1 is used for multicast. Some cheap network cards may not be supporting MAC change and will not work properly

Comment: Ah, those. I updated and mentioned one already. RPi permits change easily in their kernel cmdline.txt thing. And the reason for changing is mostly privacy issues like "I do not want that my neighbors (not family) will know what hardware I buy". I indeed do not change macs on PCs and servers.

Comment: you can change the rule you mentioned to say "the second digit should be `2`, `6`, `a` or `e`" in order to include the other rule too

Comment: Yeah, that will be safest thing. I updated the answer again.

Comment: Hello, I know all that things about MAC addresses, I'm only courious about specific `nmap` behaviour: when I `nmap` hosts on the Internet, i. e. `spi0n.com`, there is no MAC address in the response, but when I check my RPi there is one :) Is this LAN/WAN specific?

Comment: Yes, if you do scan from machine that is in same network segment as your Pi, then nmap will check and report MAC address of remote host being scanned.